# TAB key does not work for auto-completing in Auctex

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am using Emacs 24.1 on windows XP/7.
TAB/RET key works for auto-completing in elisp mode, 
*scratch* and even ESS mode.

When I write tex file using Auctex, hitting TAB key 
jumps to the next line and doesn't auto-complete the
input. C-i could auto-complete the input in Auctex.
but it takes two keys. Any suggestions to solve this?